# retornar en parametros de salida y en su nombre? funciones C

Tags: c, linux, funciones

soy nueva en programacion, y tengo una confusion con este tema. No entiendo muy bien esto de los parametros de salida y lo que la funcion devuelve en su nombre. pongo un ejemplo de ejercicio.

"Escribir una funcion que reciba un arreglo de enteros y su dimension y retorne en tres parametros de salida el mayor, el menor y el promedio de los elementos del arreglo. La funcion debe retornar en su nombre EXITO si el arreglo no estaba vacio y ERROR si el vector estaba vacio. si estaba vacio los parametros de salida no deben alterarse."

mi duda es, cual es la diferencia entre un parametro de salida y lo que retorna la funcion, y ademas no entiendo como retornar tres parametros de salida, no es uno solo el valor de retorno????
gracias por su ayuda, estoy muy confundida.

Comment: Quizas te esten pidiendo retornar un `struct`, y en al retornar struct justamente estas retornando un solo elemento, pero lo bueno de la estructura es que puedes guardar varios datos. Aunque para mi no tiene mucho sentido la pregunta, si puedes dar un contexto de que temas ya has llevado podriamos especular a que se refiere, este tipo de preguntas las debes hacer a tu tutor. :)

Answer (score 1):

En C, toda función tiene un tipo de retorno y cero o más parámetros:

```
//             ~~~~~ parámetros
  int funcion( float );
//~~~ retorno
```

Como norma general, los parámetros son los valores con los que se alimenta a la función. Sin embargo, y dado que dichos parámetros pueden ser punteros, es posible utilizar los parámetros como un medio de que la función devuelva información al exterior. Cuando un parámetro se usa para que la función devuelva un resultado, se entiende que ese parámetro es de salida.

Un ejemplo típico es la función `scanf`:

```
int valor;
scanf("%d",&valor);
```

En este ejemplo `scanf` utiliza el segundo parámetro como vehículo para devolver información (en vez del `return`).

**¿Por qué se recurre a esta práctica?**

La norma general dicta que los parámetros deben ser de entrada, sin embargo, como toda norma general tiene sus excepciones.

En el caso de `scanf` el motivo que justifica utilizar parámetros de salida es que esta función acepta un número indeterminado de parámetros:

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d ...",&v1,&v2,&v3,...);
```

Y con este requisito en mente no existe un mecanismo estándar que permita devolver todos estos valores a través del tipo de retorno.

Sin embargo, si el número de parámetros de salida es fijo, se pueden llegar a eliminar haciendo uso del return. Para ello podemos crear una estructura que agrupe todos los valores de salida:

```
struct retorno
{
  int val1;
  int val2;
  int val3;
};

// Via parametros de salida
void func(int* val1, int* val2, int* val3);

// Via return
struct retorno funcion();
```

Al menos en C, por legibilidad, se suele optar por los parámetros de salida ya que la gestión de estructuras hace que el código fuente sea un poco feo. Sin embargo en C++, donde existen utilidades bastante potentes, la tendencia pasa por eliminar los parámetros de salida:

```
std::tuple<int,int,int> funcion()
{
  // ...
}

int val1, val2, val3;

// Para recuperar los tres valores
std::tie(val1, val2, val3) = funcion();

// Si queremos ignorar algun valor
std::tie(val1, std::ignore, std::ignore) = funcion();

// C++17
auto [val1,val2,val3] = funcion();
```